# How to integrate swagger to my existing java project ?

Tags: java, rest, swagger-2.0

I have an existing project having java code for Rest Web Services. I integrated Swagger to the java project which in turn added lot of annotations and descriptions, messing up my existing code. Is there a way to integrate swagger and read values from another class instead of messing up my existing class?

Comment: I think you'll get more help if you can provide some specific information.  When you say you "integrated Swagger to the Java project," can you explain more specifically what you did, and how you did it?

Comment: Also, please explain how it messed up your code.

Comment: I am adding annotations for api responses too mentioning the cause of each error response. Writing a 2 line description for each error response for all the APIs is reducing the code's readability.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the following annotation with you java file:

```
@Api(value = "myAdmin", description = "Operation pertaining Admin UI")
```

Other things are taken care by the RestContoller and all byt itself.
This annotation is not at all messing up with your code.